# Java - Compare two strings and assign value to third variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, compare

this is my first so I'll try to add as much info as possible so I don't get yelled at. :-)

What I am trying to do is I have 2 variables that grab text from 2 fields and take only the first character from each and assign it to those values.

This is the code that I use to get the strings. They are 2 separate calls as you would.

```
try { var_ContactSurname = var_ContactSurname.substring(0,1);
    }
catch (Exception e){
}
```

I have the above again with a different variable. Now to this point it does what I want. It grabs the first letter from the fields and assigns it to the variables.

So at this point I have two variables (say with an example charater of D and R).

var_ContactSurname = R
var_ContactLicenceNumber = D

What I want to do is compare those two variables and if they match I want to return a value of TRUE, else FALSE if they don't match.

That value has to be a string as well and be assigned to a new variable called var_ContactValidate.

```
if (var_ContactLicenceNumber.toLowerCase().equals()var_ContactSurname.toLowerCase()){
var_ContactValidate == "TRUE";
}
else {
var_ContactValidate == "FALSE";
}
```

No you may notice that there might be some code missing. I am using a rules engine that does a lot of the functions for me. I can use raw Java code to do other things (like this compare)...but that's the compare that I am having a problem with.

Any ideas for that compare would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?  It looks like the last code block you have almost works (there is an error in it - the close-paren right after `equals` should be at the end).  Also you could consider using [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Is `var_ContactLicenceNumber.toLowerCase().equals()var_ContactSurname.toLowerCase()` a typo in the question? It should be `var_ContactLicenceNumber.toLowerCase().equals(var_ContactSurname.toLowerCase()) ` or some equivalent to it... The compiler must have showed this issue when trying to compile

Comment: Sorry, question is how to do I get the compare to work.

What I want to do is compare those two variables and if they match I want to return a value of TRUE, else FALSE if they don't match.

I'll try fixing that bracket fix

Comment: You also have the assignments to `TRUE` and `FALSE` with `==`, while you should use only `=`.

Comment: You should not use 'catch Exception' around the substring call.  All that can be thrown here is NullPointerException and StringIndexOutOfBoundsException which you should avoid happening instead of catching.

Answer (score 5):

1. i would use the `String` method [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)
2. to assign a value to a field, use a single `=`, not double (`==`).

Comment: +1 Looks like the = vs == thing is your main problem. Also there was part of the answer that explained that, but got removed in an edit?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (var_ContactLicenceNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(var_ContactSurname){
var_ContactValidate = "TRUE";
}
else {
var_ContactValidate = "FALSE";
}
```

check it

Comment: You're missing a paren, and could indent the assignment statements (SO wouldn't let me edit though since that's < 6 chars).

Comment: This one worked well. just getting another error. But I might be able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what already said - a simpler & more elegant version (without the `if` condition) could be:

```
var_ContactValidate = Boolean.toString(
     var_ContactLicenceNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(var_ContactSurname))
    .toUpperCase();
```

Comment: This is not an improvement. The result values might change in the future. Deriving these Strings from Boolean could confuse future programmers. Just because code is (a bit) shorter does not always mean it is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Change your whole piece of code to:

```
if (var_ContactLicenceNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(var_ContactSurname)){
var_ContactValidate == "TRUE";
}
else {
var_ContactValidate == "FALSE";
}
```

This combines the case insensitivity that you want, and passes through the second string as an argument of the .equalsIgnoreCase function.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to do with the line:
    `var_ContactValidate == "TRUE";`

If you want to assign var_ContactValidate to "TRUE" then use a single equals sign '=' as a double equals '==' compares the values instead. You may also considering using a boolean rather than a string in this case.

Comment: Thanks,

I need that var_ContactValidate to have a string of TRUE or FALSE because the rules engine that I am using will be looking for one or the other in the if statements I have to use outside of this JAVA code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that also checks for null values and empty Strings:

```
public class SurnameAndLicenseValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // FALSE
        validateSurnameAndLicense(null, "jb78hq");
        validateSurnameAndLicense("Johnson", null);
        validateSurnameAndLicense(null, null);
        validateSurnameAndLicense("", "jb78hq");
        validateSurnameAndLicense("Johnson", "");
        validateSurnameAndLicense("", "");
        validateSurnameAndLicense("johnson", "xb78hq");

        // TRUE
        validateSurnameAndLicense("Johnson", "jb78hq");
        validateSurnameAndLicense("johnson", "jb78hq");
    }

    private static String validateSurnameAndLicense(String surname,
            String license) {
        String result;
        if (surname != null
                && surname.length() > 0
                && license != null
                && license.length() > 0
                && Character.toUpperCase(surname.charAt(0)) == Character
                        .toUpperCase(license.charAt(0))) {
            result = "TRUE";
        } else {
            result = "FALSE";
        }
        System.out.println(surname + " " + license + " " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The main method is used as a unit test here. You might want to extract a real JUnit test from it, if you are into that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit there.

For what I need that would probably be a little overkill, but thank you none the less.

I did get it working with the other answers. 


Thanks again.